# DeviceAdmin add device intent from preference fragment xml

Tags: java, android, android-intent, preferences, fragment

I'm trying to make an intent from a xml fragment :

`<PreferenceScreen android:key="Admin" android:title="@string/prefTitleAdminApp" android:summary="@string/prefSumAdminApp">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
        </PreferenceScreen>`

while having this in the manifest :

```
        <receiver android:name="my.package.ARL.elements.AdminDevice"
        android:label="ARL"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/admin" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

When i click, i'm having a force close with the "No activity found to handle Intent  { act=android.intent.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN }

Where Am i wrong ? Is that possible (for device admin) ?

Is it possible to add the "extra" like this ? :

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,adminName);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,getString(R.string.adminRights));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But in xml format ? (didn't find the extra in the doc, there is only the data that look close)

Thanx

Edit: I found that it wasn't android.intent.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN but DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN.

But it seems that calling such intent don't work from xml, this is still working :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,"ARL");
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,getString(R.string.adminRights));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

If you have an idea on how to call such intent from xml, it would be great,